# pinging wireless clients is gambling

Tags: networking, ping

For browsing the internet on all computers in my house, I've setted up a small home network some months ago.
Internet works perfectly everywhere, but I have some odd problems with communication between the clients.

Pinging between the wired clients works perfectly, but pinging the wireless connected clients is pure gambling (In both directions). Sometimes it works, sometimes not, sometimes it takes some time, sometimes it works and 5 minutes later not, ...

Pinging the router works perfectly everytime from everywhere!

All clients are linux based (ubuntu, busybox, android).
DHCP is deactivated, all clients have static ip addresses. Gateway and DNS-Server is everywhere 192.168.2.1(router).

Here is picture of my network topology:
[image: network topology]

Are there any things that can cause something like this? I've read very often, that this might caused by a firewall, but i haven't installed a firewall.

If you need further information in order to help me, feel free to ask!

regards,
Simon

Comment: Is the network secured?  Because if not, you may have someone else popping onto your network, and using a duplicate IP.  A long shot, but worth looking at.

Comment: yes, i'm using WPA2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you write, that pinging the router works every time, still have you done a wireless survey, to see what WiFi channels are being used nearby? If not, give [inSSIDer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inssider) a go.

Depending on the density of neighboring access points, preferably choose a channel that's 3 channels or more from any other strong access points, as each channel covers a frequency spectrum, rather than a single frequency.

That's rarely possible, but then go for a channel no one else uses and as a last resort use the channel with fewest/weakest other access points.

Unfortunately, tools like inSSIDer won't reveal every possible interference, as it just covers WiFi access points. A lot of other things can cause interference, e.g. microwave ovens and cordless phones, and won't show up here. Even if the current channel seems to be the most suitable, try another and see if that helps. That might be enough to steer clear of the interference.

Comment: Since inSSIDer isn't working on the newest Ubuntu, i've worked with `sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning | egrep 'Cell |Encryption|Quality|Last beacon|ESSID|Channel'`. And as you mentioned there were 4 different networks on the same channel as mine. I've changed it to a complete free channel and it seems to work!:) thanks a lot!! Will test it over the time.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the fact the all clients were Linux-based. Anyway, glad it worked out for you and thanks for the command. That's neat :-)